# Why is the error about Unique items showing?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm having an error that says: A field in your source data has more unique items that can be used in a PivotTable report.

Basically, if choosing this field it won't create the report. I've just tried it manually since I get the VBA code from that manual step, but the error pops.

My source data has ~45k rows.

This is the code I'm using

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim pvtSht As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PRange As Range
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim finalCol As Long

Set wrkSht = Worksheets("Data")
Set pvtSht = Worksheets("Pivot")

finalRow = wrkSht.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
finalCol = wrkSht.Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = wrkSht.UsedRange
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set pt1 = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pvtSht.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Pivot")
pt1.RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There can't be more than 1,048,576 unique items per fields in a Pivot Table, You probably have more.

Comment: I have 45k rows. I created an index for each, using 3 columns. That may have made, in the worst case scenario, each row a unique record, not even close to the limit you mention.